# Hive - Remove substring from string

Tags: java, regex, hive, udf

I need to replace substring from a given string with empty string with the substring appearing in different positions of the string.

I want to remove the `"fruit":"apple"` from these possible combinations of the strings and expected the corresponding string:

```
{"client":"web","fruit":"apple"}   --> {"client":"web"}
{"fruit":"apple","client":"web"}   --> {"client":"web"}
{"client":"web","fruit":"apple","version":"v1.0"} --> {"client":"web","version":"v1.0"}
{"fruit":"apple"}   -->  null or empty string
```

I used `regexp_replace(str, "\,*\"fruit\"\:\"apple\"", "")` but that didn't get me the expected results. What is the right way to construct the regex?

Comment: The only problem is the trailing `,` after `"fruit":"apple"` ?

Comment: decode to json, remove that then encode again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are working with data in JSON format. Depending from included dependencies you can achieve it totally without regular expression.

For example, if you are using Google's lib Gson, then you can parse String to JsonObject and then remove property from it

```
String input = "your data";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject o = parser.parse(input).getAsJsonObject();

try {
   String foundValue = o.getAsJsonPrimitive("fruit").getAsString();
   if ("apple".equals(foundValue)) {
      o.remove("fruit");
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
String filteredData = o.toJSONString();
```

P.S. code is not final version, it might needs handling of some situations (when there is no such field, or it contains non-primitive value), need further details to cover it

P.P.S. IMO, using regex in such situatioins makes code less readable and flexible